# How can I have references of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, data-structures

Say I have two following lists.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
```

Now I want a list that contains references to these lists,

So instead of wanting

```
z = [x, y] -> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I want the following

```
z = [ref of x, ref of y]
```

How can I achieve that in Python?

Comment: But that gives me [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], so it seems its copying the lists, not just keeping the references.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: now change `x` or `y` (append to one, for example) and look at `z`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`z = [x, y]` **is** the way to use references:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> z = [x, y]
>>> x[0] = 0
>>> z
[[0, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

If you want to copy, use the [slice notation](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python) or the [copy module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

```
>>> z=[x[:],y[:]]
>>> x[0] = 11
>>> x
[11, 2, 3]
>>> z
[[0, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

`z=[x,y]` keeps the references, not the copies. This can be proved as:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> id(x),id(y)
(139643028466504, 139643028484320)
>>> z=[x,y]
>>> id(z[0]),id(z[1])
(139643028466504, 139643028484320)
```

As you can see addresses of **x and y** are similar to addresses **z[0] and z[1]**, which clearly is the definition of reference.